# storing datastore tags efficiently (for get by tags purposes)

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I've often encountered a situation where I have something like this:

```
type Article struct {
    Title   string
    User    string
    Content []byte
    Tags    []string
}
```

Where I want to be able to perform query tasks like this:

```
var articles []Article
query := datastore.NewQuery("Article")
for _, filter := range filters {
    if filter.User != "" {
        query = query.Filter("User =", filter.User)
    }
    // how to do if for finding tags
}
keys, err := DatastoreClient().GetAll(ctx, query, &articles)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return articles, nil
```

Let's say an article have the following tags `[]string{"golang", "ruby", "python", "programming"}` and I want to retrieve all articles that contain the tags `golang` and `programming`, how could I efficiently achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in array in datastore with usage of equal sign works as contains.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#properties_with_array_values_can_behave_in_surprising_ways

That means, that you need to make a query with two equal filters by this property.
Example on GQL.

```
SELECT * FROM Article WHERE Tags = "golang" AND Tags = "prgramming".
```

If `Tags` is an array, equal will behave as contains. That it. All the trick.

Comment: Wow, no idea how I missed that.. almost sounds too good to be true.. thanks a lot <3